# Image alignment

Tags: swift, macos, xcode8

I'm setting the Scaling and Alignment of an ImageView in the Attributes inspector.

But the Alignment property only works selecting a Border Type. I don't want to add any style.

I've tried this code:

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    logoImageView.layer?.contents = logoImageView.image
    logoImageView.layer?.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspect
}
```

But the image is centered and I need it left aligned.

With kCAGravityLeft I get an error and it doesn't resize.

> Misuse of NSImage and CALayer. contentsGravity is left. It should be
>   one of resize, resizeAspect, or resizeAspectFill.

Thanks in advance.